# savon nested non unique tags

Tags: ruby, savon

Im making a savon client to consume the Canada Post web service

I need to produce

```
<options>
<option>
<option-code>SO</option-code>
</option>
<option>
<option-code>PA19</option-code>
</option>
</options>
```

im building this all via a ruby hash, and the solution might be to use Builder, hopefully i can do with the hash i have

so far ive got

```
myhash[:shipment]['delivery-spec'][:options]= [
:option=>{'option-code'=>'SO'}, 
:option=>{'option-code'=>'PA19'}
]
```

this just produces one option, the last one , as obviously its the same key!
ive tried a few other ways of org the structure but the wsdl submission just fails!

any insight appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Inside your "options" hash you can create a lot of similar options passing an array, like:

```
myhash[:shipment]['delivery-spec'][:options]= [
  :option=>['option-code'=>'SO', 'option-code'=>'PA19']
]
```

Did you already try something like this?